# Page shifts when setting value - Bug in my code or latest version of chrome?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

Some background info before I explain my issue.  This doesnt happen in any other browser tested (IE, FireFox, Safari, and even older versions of chrome) however, just last week my and several of our end users chrome auto updated to version:

`Version 38.0.2125.111 m`

I started getting phone calls and emails with an application I wrote that when it initially loads some pages load and the page scrolls either to the bottom, to the middle while other pages were just fine.
I couldn't understand why this was happening as it never happened in chrome in the past and it didn't happen in any other browser.  I checked developer tools and no js/jquery issues.

I decided to spend more time on it today and what I first did is find out which pages it was happening on because it was not happening on all of my aspx pages.  Then the ones it happened on I wanted to find what was common between them.

Come to find out what is happening is in my page load event I load some initial dropdown / listbox values.  Now in one of these listboxes after loading it I set it to an initial value, simple just like so:

`lbCustomers.Items.FindByValue("SomeDefault").Selected=true;`

Wherever that control is on the page after the page has completly loaded chrome takes you to that section of the page where the control is at.  Almost like it is keeping the focus on that control.  I can easily remedy / hack this by setting the focus on some control that is at the top of the page but this just feels wrong.

So imagine you have a whole slew of dropdown controls on a page, in fact you have so many the page requires you to scroll vertically.  If I set say the last dropdown control (which is located at the bottom of the page) the page will load and will go to the bottom of the page.  Then I looked at the pages where it would open to the middle of the page, sure enough I was assigning a control located towards the middle of the page with a default value.

This is an asp.net web form project using jquery, and we also use the chosen library...can anyone confirm this in the latest version of chrome or am I Just doing something incorrectly?  Again all I am doing is setting a drop down or list box value:

`myDropDown.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected=true;`

And chrome will open the page directly where I've set this drop down / list box.

## Update

Upon further testing I went ahead and created a test aspx page with one drop down list and one list box.  Both I applied the chosen library too.  It appears that setting drop down box works fine page loads normally.  However, when I load and select the list box here is where the issue happens.  So I decided to try a regular listbox (no chosen applied)...and same thing.

**So this issue appears to be related to list boxes (irregardless if you use a library like chosen or you simply use a standard aspx listbox).  Anytime you set the listbox in code behind it moves the page to where that listbox control is located.**

### As a test

This morning I created a simple aspx page test.
I added a whole bunch of text to it and 4 controls.

- One control I added was a standard asp.net drop down list
- Second control I added was a standard asp.net list box
- The third control I added was a drop down list using chosen library
- The fourth control I added was a list box control using chosen library

When I set the selected values for any drop down (Whether it is standard or chosen) the normal page load happens, it loads at the top correctly.

When I set the selected value for **any list box (whether I use chosen or standard list box)** here is where the issue happens.  The page will load at the location
Of where the list box is located.  So this appears to be a bug in chrome for listboxes in general?

### The Test I Ran

Just add some text (a lot of it) and a listbox control to an aspx page as shown:

```
 The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    <br/><br/><br/>
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    <br/><br/><br/>
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    <br/><br/><br/>
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    <br/><br/><br/>
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    <br/><br/><br/>
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    <br/><br/><br/>
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    <br/><br/><br/>
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stickThe brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    The brown fox jumped over the candle stick
    <br/><br/><br/>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
```

Now in your page load event put this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;   
            }
        }
```

Open this page up in chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m, do you see the same issue?  Opening up in IE or firefox works fine.  Opening up in a previous version of chrome works fine, its only this version Version 38.0.2125.111 m.

Can anyone reproduce?

Comment: Actually no this is strictly listboxes.  Whether they are asp.net list boxes or listboxes that use chosen as their class.  Both cause this issue.

Comment: Can anyone please verify this in the listed chrome version?

Comment: Posted as a chrome bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=428755 includes visual studio 2013 asp.net project reproducing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that the problem lies with Chrome, not with ASP.NET, because it can be reproduced with the following HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ListBox Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 200em;">Name: <input type="text"></p>
    <select size="5">
      <option selected value="A">Apple</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

As a workaround, you can put an `autofocus` attribute on an earlier input field, if you have one:

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 200em;">Name: <input type="text" autofocus></p>
```

Comment: @JonH: Hopefully the bug will be fixed soon. Note that calling the `Focus()` method on the server control (e.g., `TextBox`) doesn't fix the problem -- the focus is set, but the page still scrolls. I was also unable to get `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` to work, either on its own, with `window.setTimeout`, or with `jQuery.ready()`.

Comment: Yep I tried those as well :)...This is definitely a bug...hopefully they will fix this.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in the latest version of chrome...cool i found a chrome bug!